# Chat welcome message missing the “Okay, I'll keep it in mind” button, hence can't be dismissed

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, chat

Seems we have some bad styling in chat.chemistry.

Here is my original question: [Chat welcome message missing the "Okay, I'll keep it in mind" button, hence can't be dismissed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/276882/chat-welcome-message-missing-the-okay-ill-keep-it-in-mind-button-hence-can?noredirect=1#comment896948_276882)

Other sites had the same issue and an administrator could fix it: https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2189/new-chat-welcome-message-ok-button-is-invisible

Comment: Oh, you didn't need to post this here. The meta.SE post suffices.

Comment: It's sometimes the other way around. People post bug reports on per site metas and once they think they didn't get enough attention, post them on meta.SE. I'm sure if devs are interested, the meta.SE post was enough to get them to look into this.

Comment: Oh, I thought the styling was in the hands of the [Chemistry moderators](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) and I suspected they do not read every meta.SE post.

Comment: No no, only SE devs (the design team) can change site CSS.

Comment: @IͶΔ - we are indeed the ones to make changes to styling. But we also keep an eye on the [meta-tag:bug] tag on all meta sites. In this case, this is likely specific to [chemistry.se], so this is the right place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks, fixed now. The chemistry.se theme has extra styling for buttons in the bottom area, and those extra styles were incorrectly applied here as well.